# LAMP setup with apache, mysql and php on different machines

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, lamp

I am pretty new to linux and LAMP setup. I want to setup a LAMP environment with AMP each on different server. I have a hard time finding a relevant document with such a configuration.

I have done the following steps so far:

```
server1:

yum install -y httpd
/sbin/service httpd restart


server2:

yum install -y mysql-libs
yum install -y mysql
yum install -y perl-DBI
yum install -y perl-DBD-MySQL
yum install -y mysql-server
/sbin/chkconfig mysqld on
/sbin/service mysqld start
mysql -u root  -e "CREATE USER 'mysqluser' IDENTIFIED by 'password'" 
mysql -u root  -e "CREATE USER 'mysqluser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED by 'password'"
mysql -u root  -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mysqluser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION"
mysql -u root  -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mysqluser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION"
mysql -u mysqluser -p password -e "CREATE DATABASE mysqldb" 
mysql -u mysqluser -p password mysqldb < /tmp/mysqlinstaller/world.sql

server 3:

yum install -y php php-mysql
sed -i "s/Listen 80/#Listen 80/g" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
yum install -y mod_ssl openssl
/sbin/service httpd restart
```

How do I enable communication between these 3 servers? Please help

Comment: You put them on the same network.

Comment: You want the web server and PHP on different machines?

Comment: All the 3 servers(different ips) are on the same network. I guess we need to change some conf files with the ip of each other so that they can integrate to work as a LAMP setup. I am not aware of those steps.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson unfortunately yes. That is the requirement

Comment: I guess it can be done with PHP-FPM. Then you configure the web server to connect to that machine instead. You should 100% have them on the same network since you don't want to open up ports to PHP-FPM to the public.

Comment: However... I do think there is a reason why you have a hard time finding any documentation on how to do it, though. :)

Comment: :( It looks like I'm stuck. I have been doing research for a few days now but in vain. Now longing for experts' assistance. Please help